# Best way to apply multiple filters to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm building a filter on some elements that have multiple data attributes. I.e. shapes and colours.

[Here is a fiddle of the listeners](https://jsfiddle.net/0yozkxy7/)

```
    $('#colour input').on('change', function(e) {
                data = ($('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#colour').val());

                filter(data);
                console.log(secondfilter);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

    $('#shape input').on('change', function(e) {
               from = ($('input[name="myRadio"]:checked', '#shape').val());

               filter(from);
               console.log(secondfilter);
               e.preventDefault();
            });
```

I need to combine the listeners but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

I've tried combining the selectors, i.e. 'square red', but there isn't a class for '.square red'. I need to filter on '.square' AND '.red'.

Sorry if this isn't clear enough!

Thanks in advance for any help/directions.

Comment: Perhaps not useful any more since the question already has a good answer, but just in case you're going to add more filters or want to use it in a more generic fashion, you could also create the filter by `map`ping the checked inputs (with a value): https://jsfiddle.net/0yozkxy7/5/

Comment: That's very useful; always good to know other methods. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
$('#colour input, #shape input').on('change', function(){

    $('#container .item').hide();

    var colour = $('#colour input:checked').val() ? '.' + $('#colour input:checked').val() : '',
        shape  = $('#shape input:checked').val() ? '.' + $('#shape input:checked').val() : '';

    $('#container .item' + colour + shape).show();
});
```

Here is [the updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0yozkxy7/3/)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!